# How can I loop through an array only after an async command is completed?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I need to save about 35 object to Mongoose.  I don't want to save the next one until the previous one is complete.

I tried the code below but it did not work.

```
function loopData(array){
  let i = array.length - 1;
  while( i >= 0){
    delete array[i]['date'];
    delete array[i]['saved'];
    let article = array[i];
    DBM.saveArticle(article).then(() => {
      i--;
      console.log('article saved', i)
    });
  }
}
```

I tried this but it did not work as myLoop is not recognized as being asynchronous:

```
function loopData(array){
  for( let i = array.length - 1 ; i-- ; i >= 0){
    delete array[i]['date'];
    delete array[i]['saved'];
    let article = array[i];
    await myLoop(i, article);
  }
}

async function myLoop(i, article) {
  let response = await DBM.saveArticle(article);
  console.log('article saved', i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same effect with recursion.

```
function loopData(array){
    DBM.saveArticle(array[0]).then(() => {
        if(array.length > 1) {
            loopData(array.slice(1));
        }
    })
}
```

This version of the method takes an array, saves the first element then calls itself with the remaining elements, if any.

Comment: I like it but can you do it using await and async?

Comment: @j.a. For what purpose?